# Determine Original Referrer of App Store Purchases

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, affiliate, referrals

I'd like to start an affiliate/commission system for my app, so that people who promote my app can earn a cut of my earnings when users purchase my app through special links.  Essentially, if Promoter A tweets a link to my app, all purchases made by users who followed the link from Promoter A will be tracked/counted, so that I can give Promoter A a percentage of my earnings.

Is there a way to do this with iTunes Connect?  I'm aware of an iTunes Affiliate Program, but (correct me if I'm wrong) that only seems to work for *me* referring users to *Apple*, not a *promoter* referring users to *my app*.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't believe you can do this with iTunes connect - either they can become affiliates in their own right or you can track the referrals through your web site, but it will be difficult if not impossible to correlate the actual purchases

Comment: @Paulw11 Yeah… I'm more than capable of setting up my own system to track how many people followed the links, but I won't be able to use those to see if they resulted into actual purchases.  :/